# Count how many time each row of dataframe A appear in each row of many elements in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataframe A with one column, 2009 rows, with many elements in each row, like:

```
                          Text
                  0       first, german, television,abide, called, ladies, dai...
                  1       party, day, hanover, cdu, first, soft, bundest...
                  2       evening,ability chancellor, merkel, berlin, israeli, ...
                  3       egypt, followers, opponent, president, must, v...
                  4       eu, commission, wants, high, youth, unemployme...
                  5       european, aviation, armament, company, eads, s...
                   ....
```

And another dataframe B ,1900 rows with only one element in each row

```
                               Word
              0                 abide
              1               ability
              2                 able
              3               abound
              4              absolve
              5            absorbent
              6           absorption
              7            abundance
             ....
```

I want to count how many time the element in all rows of dataframe `B` appear in each row of dataframe `A`

```
      Word=B.Word
      List=Word.tolist()

      #Option 1
      A.Text.str.extractall(
'({})'.format('|'.join(str(v) for v in List))
  ).groupby(level=0) 
 [0].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

  Option2
df=A.Text.str.extractall('({})'.format('|'.
join(map(str, List))))\                       
.iloc[:,0].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

I tried 2 above options, but the result returns a new data frame with the number of rows of data frame A and that of data frame B decreasing.
So, maybe they are not the right way to do this task.
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I might have what you need backward. If you need number of items in `dfB` that appear in each row of `dfA`:

```
dfA.Text.str.split(',\s?', expand=True).stack().isin(dfB.Word.tolist()).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Of if you need the number of times an item in `dfB` appears anywhere in `dfA`:

```
dfA.Text.str.split(',\s?', expand=True).stack().value_counts().reindex(dfB.Word)
```

## Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'Text':['first, german, television,abide, called, ladies',
                            'party, day, hanover, cdu, first, soft', 
                            'foo, bar, baz, zoo']})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'Word': ['first', 'german', 'party', 'soft']})
```

#### Code

```
dfA.Text.str.split(',\s?', expand=True).stack().isin(dfB.Word.tolist()).groupby(level=0).sum()
#0    2.0
#1    3.0
#2    0.0
#dtype: float64

dfA.Text.str.split(',\s?', expand=True).stack().value_counts().reindex(dfB.Word)
#Word
#first     2
#german    1
#party     1
#soft      1
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: One more minor question : If I want to see the detail .I mean before summing up ,I want to see  how many time each words in df B appear in each row df A . Which codes I can modify from your codes? .dfA.Text.str.split(',\s?', expand=True).stack().isin(dfB.Word.tolist()).groupby(level=0). doesnt work. And your codes above really save my day.Thanks